# Long-term visa for meeting

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, long-stay-visas

I was issued a 6-month visitor visa last year and I left the UK on the day I mentioned in the application form. Now I am planning to apply for a 2-year visitor visa for a meeting of a professional association as a member, and it is likely that I will attend the next meetings in 2018.

The thing is I will need the visa to sit an exam in April. Do you think it is wise to write "I will need to visit the UK repetitiously since I intend to participate in events on future dates"? I do not want to make separate applications for 6 months because there is a possibility that I won't be working for a few months, which makes the application tougher.

And a short question. Is it risky to visit the UK a few days or a week before the visitor visa expires?